# How do I embed variables as arguments to variables in Eclipse' external tools?

Tags: eclipse, external-tools

I'm trying to configure an external tool for eclipse and I want to prompt the user to select a  folder under his/her workspace. Eclipse provides a `${folder_prompt}` variable that can be used, and it's second parameter is the starting directory. So, I thought I could do something like: `${folder_prompt:"Choose a Folder":${workspace_loc}}` but this doesn't seem to work. Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works fine for me (as base directory entry in an external tool configuration). I suggest to look for other problems in your external tool configuration.

Comment: Perhaps gnome then. It remembers the last directory I used, and defaults to that instead of what I supplied.